# Liaison dans « vous aussi » ?

Tags: usage, liaisons

En France, j'ai déjà entendu l'expression « Vous aussi » (par exemple en reponse à « Bonne journée ») sans la liaison alors qu'en Suisse, j'ai entendu l'expression avec la liaison du *s*. Cependant, je ne suis pas sûr que la personne Suisse ait pour langue maternelle le français.

Est-ce une différence de langue ou de registre ? En français, faut-il faire la liaison ou non ?

Comment: Les liaisons ne sont pas toujours énoncées correctement en France. Avec ou sans, les gens comprendront. Toutefois, dans un contexte étudiant, le langage utilisé sera plus souvent du registre courant, familier, voire grossier, et les liaisons ne seront pas strictement appliquées.

Comment: Si tu ne fais pas la liaison tu devras mettre une virgule à l'écrit entre les deux mots ou de l'emphase (comme le dit lefrancophone plus bas) en italisant vous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En français, on peut ou pas faire la liaison entre *Vous* et *aussi*. C'est en tout cas [ce que stipule l'académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#46_strong-em-liaisons-em-strong).

1. Lorsqu'on fait la liaison :

   - il faut prononcer le *s* entre les deux mots (on entend *z* à l'oreille)
   - on utilise un langage plus soutenu et qui parait correct à l'oreille
2. Lorsqu'on ne fait pas la liaison :

   - on comprend le sens de l'expression
   - on a un langage courant qui peut paraître incorrect et qui peut gêner certaines personnes à l'oreille

Answer (score 4):

La page wikipedia explique bien il me semble [les liaisons françaises](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais).

Certaines sont obligatoires, d'autres facultatives (en général en rapport avec la langue soutenue), d'autres interdites.

Malheureusement je ne vois pas de cas vraiment similaire, à part l'exemple *mais aussi*, qui ferait partie des liaisons facultatives ?

En tant que français, il me semble que *vous zaussi* et *vous aussi* ont une légère différence de sens : le premier indique une association habituelle, le second une association plus autoritaire :

- Nous partons en voyage à la mer, vous zaussi (dirais-je)
- Chacun doit faire la vaisselle, vous aussi.

... mais les dictionnaires ne stipulent que le sens des formes écrites, et pas le sens des formes orales.

Comment: Ce n'est pas tellement une question d’autorité, mais plutôt de l'emphase.

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse, je suis en train d'étudier la prosodie française et ce type de commentaires me sont très utiles.

Answer (score 3):

Quoi qu'il en soit, les liaisons sont aussi un peu en fonction de la prononciation. Je pense que ceux qui préfèrent "vou-aussi" plutôt que "vou-z-aussi" veulent éviter la répétition de la "sifflante" (le s).

Il peut aussi y avoir des décalages d'une région à l'autre, comme les Lyonnais qui prononcent assez peu les S et le sud où l'on prononcent parfois le S final dans certains mots comme "moins", héritage de l'occitan.

Noter le l' dans la phrase précédente qui n'a qu'une fonction phonétique et est totalement facultatif.